# Showing a div when hovering over another element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, hide, show

Does anybody know how to go about showing a div (smoothly) when hovering over another element. e.g hover over a 'News' link and then a div with the news will appear and disappear on mouse off.

I'm guessing i would use jQuery for this but does anybody have any pointers where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

With a combination of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` (for showing/hiding the `div` with news smoothly) should do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#news').hover(function(){
        $('#details').show("slow");// You can chose, slow,fast or type milliseconds
},function(){
        $('#details').hide("slow");
});
```

You simply use `.hover()` and give it 2 arguments which are functions. The first one is executed when the mouse enters the `news` and the second one is executed when the mouse leaves `news`.
With the `show()` and `hide()` method you can add some effects. You could also use `fadeIn(), fadeout()` Or just use `fadeToggle()`,`toggle()`

**jQuery Documentation:**

- http://api.jquery.com/hover/
- http://api.jquery.com/show/
- http://api.jquery.com/hide/
- http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/
- http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/
- http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/
- http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/